# CakePHP: How to specify models while retrieving data?

Tags: php, cakephp, data-modeling

I want to retrive data with recursive level 3. The problem is that It adds all 8 linked models but I need data from only three data models. Is there any way to ignore some models or  specifically asked some models but not all. something like useModel('Model1', 'Model2')?

Comment: quick hint: look for unbind in the manual

Comment: bind or unbind only works when it's first level recursive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to use the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) behavior, which will allow you to specify find conditions like this:

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Tag', 
        'Comment' => array(
            'User')
            )
        )
    );
```

Also, in conjunction with this, it's good to set $recursive to -1 in your AppModel.

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    var $recursive = -1;
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

This will give you the finer control you need and ensure that your queries don't bloat as more relationships get added to your models over time.

Comment: It is unnecessary to set $recursive to -1. Just forget it ever existed and always use Containable.